# CodeIgniter - cannot execute procedure with couple UPDATE statements

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, mysqli

Have an issue with executing routines in CodeIgniter.

I have a routine that just updates couple mysql tables with the data specified in parameters.

Originally I received:

> Error Number: 2014
>   Commands out of sync; you can’t run this command now

Tried the solution specified at http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/96583/

```
$this->mydb->Query($sql);
```

with changed driver to mysqli

It works fine with the select statements for me but if the routine has only couple updates - it does not work.

The problem is that there is no error message is returned. It behaves like it is successfully run, but tables are not updated.

NOTE: there should not be an issue with routine itself since if I print the query in question and try to execute this in MySQL Workbench - tables are updated correctly.

Any advises are appreciated.

Comment: Just a though: are you sure the values you update aren't already the ones to got? If that's the case it returns true, but no changes gets made. What does http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php give?

Comment: Please disregard the question; I have just resolved the issue - it appeared that issue occurs due to the fact that before this routine I called another one with $this->db->query. Will need to update the whole project to use $this->mydb->Query only.

Thanks

Comment: Robin, I definitely sure about this since if I print_r this and copy/paste into the Workbench and execute - data is updated :)

Comment: @AlexG please answer your own question and mark it as closed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$this->mydb->Query used in the whole project for each query has solved the issue

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the dbdriver in the config file to `mysqli`:

`$db['default']['dbdriver'] = "mysqli";`

Comment: Thanks for suggestion; unfortunately cannot verify that now since I am not working with CodeIgniter anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
function call( $procedure )
{
    $result = @$this->db->conn_id->query( $procedure );

    while ( $this->db->conn_id->next_result() )
    {
        //free each result.
        $not_used_result = $this->db->conn_id->use_result();

        if ( $not_used_result instanceof mysqli_result )
        {
            $not_used_result->free();
        }
    }

    return $result;

}
```